# Sequential random choice in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to randomly choose from an array but the requirement is that the elements of the output array will increase by one (and start at zero). For example, if I want to get 5 numbers between 0 and 5 then one could do

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(6), 5)
array([5, 0, 5, 2, 5])
```

where, in this case, I would like this to be:

```
array([2, 0, 2, 1, 2])
```

Another example, if

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(6), 5)
array([1, 1, 1, 4, 2])
```

I am trying to "rebase" this in such a manner that it will be

```
array([0, 0, 0, 2, 1])
```

Final example...select 15 numbers between 0 and 5

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(6), 15)
array([4, 5, 3, 0, 4, 5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4])
```

where eventually I want to end up with

```
array([3, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Why are you generating random values between 0 and 5 only to rebase it later? Why not just generate between 0 and 2, or 0 and 4?

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge How would you do that and ensure there are no gaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking to do is replace each entry in your original array `x` by its *index* in the array of unique elements of `x` (in sorted order). For example, if `x` is `np.array([7, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2])`, the unique elements of `x` are `[2, 6, 7]`, and we want to replace each number with its position in that array of unique elements: that is, replace each `2` with `0`, each `6` with `1` and each `7` with `2`.

The [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function does both these jobs: it finds the (sorted) array of unique elements for you, and if you pass `return_inverse=True`, `np.unique` will *also* give you a second return value that contains exactly the indices you're after. So all you need to do is call `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True`, throw away the first return value, and keep the second. Examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.unique([5, 0, 5, 2, 5], return_inverse=True)[1]
array([2, 0, 2, 1, 2])
>>> x = np.array([4, 5, 3, 0, 4, 5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4])
>>> np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)[1]
array([3, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks Mark, that was new to me. Your comments are very helpful. 6502's answer below shows a similar approach, yours is more self-contained. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is starting from a randomly chosen array

```
x = np.random.choice(np.arange(6), 5)
```

then collect the unique values and sorting them

```
v = sorted(set(x))
```

then map the original value to the index in `v`:

```
result = [v.index(y) for y in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original sequence contains only unique elements, sorting based approaches like `np.unique` are actually a bit wasteful at O(n log n) since an O(n) solution is available (assuming n >= k where k is the size of the set to choose from):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
to_choose_from = [1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 'hello', ()]
>>> n = 12
>>> 
>>> k = len(to_choose_from)
# make sure no duplicates - skip this if you happen to know
>>> assert len(set(to_choose_from)) == k
>>> 
>>> chc = np.random.randint(0, k, (n,))
>>> chc
array([4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 5, 6, 1, 6, 6])
>>> 
>>> occur = np.zeros((k,), int)
>>> occur[chc] = 1
>>> idx, = np.where(occur)
>>> occur[idx] = np.arange(idx.size)
>>> result = occur[chc]
>>> result
array([2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4])
```